# Exist a function composed by simple continuous functions that $f:\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb N$?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Im not mathematician so I dont know if this question is trivial or not. I was thinking if exist some function composed of simple continuous functions (trigonometric, exponential, powers, roots, logs, etc...) that work as Kronecker delta or the floor function that map from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb N$.

If the answer is a "NO" then I have a complementary subquestion: exist a limit of a function composed by simple continuous functions that make the same? What Im asking is about a function that in some limit (to 0, to infinity, to X, etc...) does the function of Kronecker delta or floor function.

I want to know if exist something similar to Kronecker delta or floor function that is defined in an analytic context, maybe with the use of limits or integration. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: sry, I didnt noticed that the function, obviously,  cannot be analytic because is discrete. What I was trying to say is if exist a way to construct these type of discrete functions with functions composed of simple continuous functions not just by definition.

Sry very much for the wrong language and complication.

EDIT2: "challenge" expanded to the [sign function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function).

Comment: What do you mean by _analytic_?

Comment: Anaylitic functions are continuous, so any analytic function $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb N$ must be constant.

Comment: There is no such thing as "a limit of an analytic function". There can be such a thing as a limit of a *sequence* of analytic functions.

Comment: The "fractional part" function, being periodic, has a representation as a Fourier series; if you subtract that from $x$, you get the floor function.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson sry I dont understand... you mean that every limit is a limit of a sequence?

Comment: You're looking for a function. It makes no sense to ask for a function as the limit of a function.

Comment: The only analytic functions of the kind you want are constant by Picards theorem.

Comment: Can I attempt to paraphrase the question? Are you looking for an analytic function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb C$ such that when we restrict the domain to $\Bbb N$ we get some special function (floor, Kronecher delta, etc.)?

Comment: @EricStucky I think the question is rather: Does there exist a sequence $f_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that, for $n \rightarrow \infty$ $f_n\rightarrow g$ where $g$ is the Kronecker delta, or the floor function. Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: @sonystarmap this is a possibility but Im not asking for what Eric Stucky says... the function must map only to $\Bbb N$ not $\Bbb C$. But my proposal is wrong... I delete it by now.

Comment: @Masacroso: Are you sure that you want the whole function to map to $\Bbb N$? Or would it be enough for the function to map to $\Bbb N$ after the domain has been restricted?

Comment: @Eric Stucky whole function, this is what Im asking, for every real number.The fllor function or Kronecker delta are functions over $\Bbb R$ that map to $\Bbb N$ so I want to know some analytic (or limit) form for these discrete functions, if it is possible, maybe it isnt possible, I dont know.

Comment: @Masacroso in the example I provide, the sequence $f_n$ maps to $\mathbb{R}$ but in the limit $f$ maps to $\mathbb{N}$ is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Hey look: $\lfloor x\rfloor = x - \frac12 + \frac1\pi \tan^{-1}(\cot(\pi x))$. Can you find the catch?

Comment: Yes, thank you @Rahul... for some reason Im unable to upvote your commentary.

Comment: See: <http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1810859/analytic-floor-function-why-this-seems-to-work>. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT2:** I added a plot that should illustrate the convergence of $f_n^{0.3}(x)$.

**EDIT:** Obviously, $\sqrt[n]{x}$ does not converge towards a function that is $0$ everywhere except for $x=1$. It converges towards a function that is $1$, everywhere except for $x=0$. I've fixed this.

Referring to the part about a sequence of function converging towards the Kronecker delta (if I understood the question correctly).

Recall, that the Kronecker delta is defined as 
\begin{align}
\delta_{ij} = \begin{cases} 1, \quad i=j \\ 0, \quad i\not = j\end{cases}
\end{align}
Now consider the sequence $f_n: [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with 
\begin{align}
f_n(x) = 1-\sqrt[n] x \rightarrow f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, \quad x = 0\\ 0, \quad x\not =0\end{cases}
\end{align}
or more similar to the Kronecker delta with $j\in [0,1]$ and again $f_n^j: [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
\begin{align}
f_n^j(x) = 1-\sqrt[n] {(x-j)^2} \rightarrow f^j(x) = \begin{cases} 1, \quad x=j\\ 0, \quad  x\not = j\,\wedge 0\leq x \leq 1\end{cases}
\end{align}
Since $f^j:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and $f^j(i)\equiv \delta_{ij}$ for $i,j\in [0,1]$, $f_n^j$ converges towards the Kronecker delta (on $[0,1]$).

The following plot shows $f_n^{0.3}(x)$ for different values of $n$ which converges towards $f_\infty^{0.3}(x) =f^{0.3}(x)= \delta_{x,0.3}$

[image: $f_n^{0.3}(x)$ for different values of $n$]

And here is an extension onto $\mathbb{R}$.

Simply use $f^j_n(x) = 1-\sqrt[n]{h^j(x)}$ with $h^j(x) = 1-\frac{1}{1-(x-j)^2}$. Then $h_j(j) = 0$ and $h_j(x)\not = 0$ for $x\not = j$ and thus $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

Here you can see a plot of $f_n^{2.5}(x)$ for $-4<x<4$.
[image]

Comment: You can extend the function to $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $[0,1]$ if you find a function $h_j(x)$ that has the property $h_j(j)=1$ and $0\leq h_j(i)<1$ when $i\not = j$. Then define $f_n^j(x) = \sqrt[n]{h_j(x)}$. This could for example be the Normal distribution with $\mu =j$ and normalizing $\sigma$.

Comment: Something like this, how you transform the $0\leq x < 1$ to $0$, just by definition? I want a way, if exists, to map to the zero directly not just by definition. Thank you anyway, its my fault I cant explain correctly :S

Comment: Maybe I dont understand the notation of $f_n$, this means this is a recursive function, a sequence?

Comment: No this means that it is a sequence. And the fact that $f(x)=0$ for $0\leq x < 1$ is not by definition, but because the $n$th square root converges to exactly this if $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Oh damn, no that is wrong, it is $1$ everywhere except for $x=0$, let me correct that.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are doing, this was exactly was I was trying to do, yes.

Comment: I'll try to come up with something for the floor function.

Comment: now just using a trigonometric function or composition of trigonometric functions it seems easily to expand the domain of the function to all $\Bbb R$ because you are using a domain of $[0,1]$

Comment: Simply use $f^j_n(x) = 1-\sqrt[n]{h^j(x)}$ with $h^j(x) = 1-\frac{1}{1-(x-j)^2}$. Then $h_j(j) = 0$ and $h_j(x)\not = 0$ for $x\not = j$ and thus $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can create Fourier series, the limit of which are discontinuous (and have only natural numbers as their range). However, traditional Fourier series are periodic and I therefore suspect that covering the whole of $\mathbb N$ is rather difficult.

Since Bessel functions are orthogonal on the interval $(0, +\infty)$ it may be possible to create a series, the limit of which is $\lfloor x \rfloor$ for all $x \gt 0$.

The "sign" function, $s(x)$ can certainly be achieved by Fourier series, $F(x)$ on $(-l,l)$ for some $l \in \mathbb R$. To continue the function to infinity, we could defined the function in just three intervals
$$s(x) = \begin{cases} -1 & -\infty \lt x \le -l \\ F(x) & -l \lt x \lt l \\ 1 & l \le x \lt \infty \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution to represent floor function under continuous real functions. My idea come from periodical functions (sine, cosine, etc...) that because they are periodic they can represent naturals numbers under the expression of a continuous function (in a similar way zeta Riemann function express prime numbers by it zeros).

The problem that I had in this attempt was that periodical functions are supersymmetric for what I was searching, because they come, in some sense, from the division of a circle. In other words is the same to say that periodical functions cannot be monotonic functions.

I was trying to divide any real number into it entire part and it fractional part using the cosine with something like $\cos(2\pi x_e+2\pi x_r)$ where $x_e$ is the entire part and $x_r$ is the fractional part. The problem is that, by symmetry, the function cant differentiate between $x_r$ and $x_r+0.5$ (for $x_r \in (0,0.5)$). But what I dont see the first time is that this problem can be fixed just iterating the function at the moment where the value of the subtract have a value of zero.

In others words something like

$$f(x_{n+1})=x_n-\arccos(\cos (2\pi x_n))$$

Note that $\cos(\arccos a)=a$ (if $a \in [-1,1]$ ofc), but $\arccos(\cos a)\ne a$ for $a>\pi$ because trigonometric functions dont have real inverses.

When *n* reach a point then the iteration represent the floor function (the number of *n* to reach the equilibrium point depends on how close is $x_0$ of $\lceil x_0\rceil$). I dont know if is possible to get a explicit formula for this iteration but in any case

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_{n})=\lfloor x_0\rfloor$$

Maybe a better and more efficient way to do this using more periodic functions that just one.